# @PreAuthorize on child class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following classes

```
public abstract class BaseCotroller {

    @RequestMapping("/m")
    public String m() {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping("/n")
    public String n() {
        ...
    }
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class ACotroller extends BaseController {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @Override
    public String m() {
        return super.m();
    }
}
```

@PreAuthorize gets applied for m, but not for n, though it should as @PreAuthorize is specified at the class level.
Or do I missed sonething?

Answer (score 1):

If you think a bit more on this, `@PreAuthorize` not working on your parent overridden method makes a perfect sense. You have this annotation for the whole class and it is applied to all of its public methods and in this case `ACotroller.m()`. According to Spring your method has been validated. The same way you can call within `m()` not `super.m()`, but a method defined in some other bean. Having `@PreAuthorize` doesn't mean that calls from your method should be also validated. In order to understand how this works in detail you can see the `PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes()` method.

Now to answer your question - you must annotate the base controller class with `@PreAuthorize` to have its methods secured.